# Render multiple pages to pdf files using PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, phantomjs, render

I need help on rendering multiple pages to pdf files using PhantomJS. Once PhantomJS is rendering one page another instance cannot be called until it finishes previous execution. I believe it will need some type of callback and recursion method.

below is the code to render a single page:

```
someUrl = "https://www.google.com/";

var phantom = require('phantom');
phantom.create(function(ph){
    ph.createPage(function(page) {
        page.open(someUrl, function(){
            page.render('google.pdf'); //needs to wait for this to finish
            ph.exit();                 //to call itself for the next url
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: @ArtjomB. thanks for responding i just added the simplest code to render a single page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need two things for recursion:

- a condition when to stop the recursion (URLs left in the list decreases to 0) and
- a value that is built up or reduced (URLs in the list are taken out on each "iteration").

Code:

```
var urls = ["http://domain1.tld", "http://domain2.tld/path"];

var phantom = require('phantom');
phantom.create(function(ph){
    ph.createPage(function(page) {
        function render(urls, callback) {
            if (urls.length == 0) {
                console.log("Exiting...");
                ph.exit();
                if (callback) callback();
                return;
            }
            var url = urls[0];
            page.open(url, function(){
                page.render('screen_'+url.replace(/[\/:]/g, "_")+'.pdf');
                render(urls.slice(1), callback);
            });
        }
        render(urls); // TODO: use a callback if you need to
    });
});
```